# Is there a more effecient way to select elements of a css class?

Tags: css, html

I'm try to learn how to make websites without using tables to align elements. Currently I'm working on the navigation bar. Is there a more efficient/OOP-ish way to select different elements of my nav class?

[image: Messy css code]

Thanks ahead for the help!

Comment: I think that is the correct way. because you need different style for each one.

Comment: Please post actual CSS and HTML, not pictures of them.

Comment: What is inefficient about this exactly? Looks to me like you're writing good CSS. Only thing that could maybe make it more efficient would be using some kind of CSS-preprocessor like Sass or Less, but if you're just learning, you might not be ready for that yet (though it's pretty easy to get going!).

Comment: Oh the irony -- it probably took more effort to post the screenshot of code than to copy-paste the code.

Answer (score 2):

If each one needs a specific style, then there's no better way than giving them classes. However, if you want to apply a style to all but the first, for example, then there are ways of selecting specific children without classes, such as the first child, last child, and *nth* child.

Here's an example, where the first button gets a left margin but none of the others do:

```
.nav li {
    margin: 0;
}

.nav li:first-child {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```